# Is there a way to sync podcasts wirelessly without Zune?

Tags: sync, wireless-sync, podcast, macos

First off, Marketplace in the UK does not have Podcasts so that is ruled out.

I can get the podcasts onto my phone using Mac Connector but when I do this the 'Subscribe' link under the podcast on the phone doesn't work. By this I mean I open it, it lists Number of downloads to keep etc. I 'Confirm' and then I'm returned to the podcast but the 'Subscribe' button is still there. (Is this a bug with WP7?)

How can I get it to sync wirelessly?

**Update:** Although Mac Connector will sync podcasts from iTunes, it apparently does not transfer the URL meaning it isn't possible to subscribe on the phone using the default 'Music & Videos' app. As mentioned, syncing with Zune from a PC does do this so if you can sync once from Zune on a PC, you can then enable wireless syncing on the phone. This is what I have done but it still required a PC and Zune software.

**2nd Update:** After upgrading to Tango and having to perform a  factory reset after signing up for an Outlook address I cannot seem to get the subscription settings back again - even after syncing with Zune. Now it seems there is no way to update podcasts without connecting to a PC ...

Comment: So I took it into work, installed Zune on my work PC, went to select the wireless sync option in Zune settings but it wouldn't allow me to do so until I had wireless network on my phone (my wireless is at home, no wireless at work). Fortunately though now when I chose 'Subscribe' on the phone it allows me to (presumably it saved the feed URL, why it can't do this with the Mac Connector is beyond me).

Comment: Please consider edit you question with this comment. ;)

Comment: OK, but it still doesn't really answer the question. If I hadn't been able to access a PC with Zune on, I still would not have been able to wirelessly sync.

Comment: My podcasts sync wirelessly, although they were originally set up within Zune (from UK too).

Answer (score 2):

Try a podcast app like [Bringcast](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/apps/e5abef38-d413-e011-9264-00237de2db9e).